# Adding regression to scatter plot in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, scatter-plot, scatter

I want to add regression to my scatter plot in R and to make elevation independent while snowfall dependent. I know how to construct a simple scatter plot - but using regression and making elevation independent while snowfall dependent - is something I stuck with... Many thanks!

Code I have so far to create simple scatter plot:

```
> elevation=c(12, 34, 32, 12, 11, 14, 56, 75, 43)
> snowfall=c(6, 52, 41, 25, 22, 9, 43, 67, 32)
> snowfallElevationPlot = data.frame(elevation=elevation, snowfall=snowfall)
> plot(elevation, snowfall)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `abline` as in:

```
# Estimating the model
model <-  lm(snowfall~elevation, data=snowfallElevationPlot)

# Plot 
plot(elevation, snowfall)

# Adding the regression line to the plot
abline(model)
```

This produces

[image]

Comment: +1, although I think the OP would learn more by deducing this from the documentation of `lm` and `abline` himself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But for some reason it does not work for me - I get a following error: Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: @AndreiIvanov See my edit, I forgot including `plot(elevation, snowfall)`, now it fixed :D

Comment: Thanks a lot - I am realy new to this, but it has to be done quick!

Answer (score 3):

Building a linear model is done using the `lm` function. Plotting that line in your plot is done using `abline`. The examples in the documentation of those functions should be enough to get you started.